# Inverse Fourier Transform Proof

Tags: fourier-analysis, proof-writing, transformation

I am aware of how Fourier Transformation and Fast Fourier Transformation works, however I do not understand the logic of the inverse of FFT.

Could someone explain why the inverse fourier transformation of $X_k$ is $\dfrac{1}{2^k} X_k$, assuming that $X_k$ is the actual fourier transformation matrix over an Abelian group $(Z_2)^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform over $\Bbb{Z}_2^n$ is different from the FFT (which is over $\Bbb{Z}_{2^n}$).  The Fourier transform over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ is

$$H' = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

so the Fourier transform over $\Bbb{Z}_2^n$ is

$$H'^{\otimes n}$$

Since $H' \cdot H' = 2 I$, it follows that

$$H'^{\otimes n} \cdot \frac{1}{2^n} H'^{\otimes n} = I$$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand, I understood your statement about $\Bbb{Z}_2^n$ being different from. But how would I prove this via induction on $k$

Comment: My argument proves that without induction..